# Is there a faster way to get file metadata than by using the shell COM component?

Tags: windows, vb.net, filesystems

Reading various answers here and elsewhere, I pieced together this bit to get the file metadata that I need:

```
Public Class windows_metadata_helper
    Public Shared shell As New Shell32.Shell
    Public Shared indices_of_interest As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Public Shared path_index As Integer

    Shared Sub New()
        'snipped long piece code for figuring out the indices of the attributes that I need, they are stored in indices_of_interest, for example 0:Name
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function get_interesting_data(path) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(path)
        Dim f_dir = shell.NameSpace(fi.DirectoryName)
        Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        For Each item In f_dir.Items()
            If f_dir.GetDetailsOf(item, path_index) = fi.FullName Then
                For Each kvp In indices_of_interest
                    Dim val = f_dir.GetDetailsOf(item, kvp.Key)
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(val) Then data.Add(kvp.Value, val)
                Next
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Return data
    End Function
End Class
```

Its not the most efficient code in the world, namely getting the path attribute of each file in the directory to identify the file I'm actually interested in. Optimizing this to only read the path attribute of each file once makes it around 50% faster (tested by letting it take the first file it finds whether its the right one or not) but regardless, its far slower than expected.

It needs to fetch 24 attributes from each file and it needs to find around 20k files from within ~100k, currently this takes an entire hour.

Profiling tells me that CPU is the bottleneck and whatever is taking up the cycles I can't see since its 99% inside the Shell32.Folder.GetDetailsOf method.

Is there a faster way to get the metadata? Answer doesn't have to be vb or .net specific.

Comment: The only attribute you list is column 0 - Name.  This particular attribute (Property) is directly available on your `item` object as I suspect many of the remaining 23 items are also directly exposed on the [FolderItem Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/folderitem).  Why do more work by calling `Folder.GetDetailsOf` to retrieve data that is already retrieved?

Comment: @TnTinMn ah good catch, vs didn't automatically resolve the folderitem type and I didn't bother to check so I didn't know it had those properties. Out of the properties it has though, only 2 are useful - path and modify date. The rest like bitrate, copyright, company, etc I still need to get with that crazy slow method though.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are seeking maximum speed, I suggest that you enable `Option Strict` for your code and make the necessary modifications that will be suggested by the IDE.  This will eliminate unnecessary type conversions.

For instance,

```
Public Shared Function get_interesting_data(path) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

should be:

```
Public Shared Function get_interesting_data(path As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

Instead of enumerating the `Shell32.Folder.Items` collection,  use the [Shell32.Folder.ParseName Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/folder-parsename) to directly retrieve a `FolderItem` object.  This object can be cast to a `Shell32.ShellFolderItem` that will allow using the [ShellFolderItem.ExtendedProperty method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/shellfolderitem-extendedproperty).

> There are two ways to specify a property. The first is to assign the
> property's well-known name, such as "Author" or "Date", to sPropName.
> However, each property is a member of a Component Object Model (COM)
> property set and can also be identified by specifying its format ID
> (FMTID) and property ID (PID). An FMTID is a GUID that identifies the
> property set, and a PID is an integer that identifies a particular
> property within the property set.
>
> **Specifying a property by its FMTID/PID values is usually more
> efficient than using its name**. To use a property's FMTID/PID values
> with ExtendedProperty, they must be combined into an SCID. An SCID is
> a string that contains the FMTID/PID values in the form "FMTID**PID",
> where the FMTID is the string form of the property set's GUID. For
> example, the SCID of the summary information property set's author
> property is "{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9} 4".

Many FMTID/PID values can be found under links presented at [Windows Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/props).
You can find the [full property table here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wsp/2dbe759c-c955-4770-a545-e46d7f6332ed) (scroll down).

Putting this together for some selected properties:

```
Public Shared Function get_interesting_data(path As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(path)
    Dim f_dir As Shell32.Folder = shell.NameSpace(fi.DirectoryName)

    ' instead of enumerating f_dir.Items to find the file of interest
    ' directly retrieve the item reference
    Dim item As Shell32.ShellFolderItem = DirectCast(f_dir.ParseName(fi.Name), Shell32.ShellFolderItem)

    Dim scid_Bitrate As String = "{64440490-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 4"    ' Audio: System.Audio.EncodingBitrate
    Dim scid_Title As String = "{F29F85E0 - 4.0FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9} 2"  ' Core: System.Title
    Dim scid_Created As String = "{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC} 15"   ' Core: System.DateCreated
    Dim scid_Copyright As String = "{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 11" ' Core: System.Copyright
    Dim scid_Publisher As String = "{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 30" ' Media: System.Media.Publisher
    Dim scid_FullDetails As String = "{C9944A21-A406-48FE-8225-AEC7E24C211B} 2" ' PropList: System.PropList.FullDetails

    Dim bitrate As Object = item.ExtendedProperty(scid_Bitrate)
    Dim title As Object = item.ExtendedProperty(scid_Title)
    Dim created As Object = item.ExtendedProperty(scid_Created)
    Dim copyright As Object = item.ExtendedProperty(scid_Copyright)
    Dim publisher As Object = item.ExtendedProperty(scid_Publisher)
    Dim fullDetails As Object = item.ExtendedProperty(scid_FullDetails)

    Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    ' save the retrieved properties

    Return data
End Function
```

I do not know if this technique of retrieving the properties is faster than you have currently using `GetDetailsOf`, but the other changes should make some improvement.