# Updated equivalent code for using Shell in VB.NET with FolderItem.GetDetailsOf

Tags: vb.net

I'm hoping someone is able to point me in the correct direction on this. I've spent hours trying to get my code to work without success.

I wrote a program in Visual Studio using VB.NET that would open a directory, iterate through all the files, and rename each/copy them to to a new folder. I'm now trying to get the program to read a particular attribute of each file and include that in the file name. This will either be the Media Created or Date Created attribute. It appears I can do this using the **Folder.GetDetailsOf** method.

The example code given by Microsoft for VB is as shown below:

```
Private Sub btnGetDetailsOf_Click()
    Dim objShell  As Shell
    Dim objFolder As Folder

    Set objShell = New Shell
    Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\WINDOWS")

    If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Dim objFolderItem As FolderItem
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("clock.avi")

        If (Not objFolderItem Is Nothing) Then
            Dim szItem As String
            szItem = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 2)
        End If

        Set objFolderItem = Nothing
    End If

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, when trying to compile I get lots of errors, including Shell, Folder, and FolderItem not being defined.

After lots of searching and reading articles I've got to this point with my code, but it throws an error when trying to set objFolderItem.

```
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(c:\folder)
Dim fileArray As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
Dim file As FileInfo

Dim objShell As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFolderItem As Object

objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(c:\folder) 'create folder object

For Each file In fileArray
    objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(file.Name) 'create file object
    MsgBox(objFolder.getdetailsof(objFolderItem, 201))
Next file
```

When I check the running code it appears objShell.NameSpace doesn't return anything.

Can someone advise how I can create objShell correcting in VB.NET or provide an updated version of Microsoft's example code so I can use that as a basis?

Thanks

Comment: Please add a link to the article you're referring to.

Comment: Add a project COM reference to "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation".  Then see: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51145823/2592875](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51145823/2592875).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I managed to get this working by importing Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation and using the code below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim objShell As Object
        Dim objFolder As Object

        objShell = New Shell32.Shell
        objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("D:\FOLDERNAME")

        If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
            Dim objFolderItem As Object

            objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("FILENAME")

            MsgBox(objFolderItem.name & " " & objFolder.getdetailsof(objFolderItem, 208))

            objFolderItem = Nothing
        End If

        objFolder = Nothing
        objShell = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Many thanks for your help again

Answer (score -1):

That's a lot of code for a simple problem.  You don't need to use the shell.  To copy/move:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(<SourceDir>, <DestinationDir>)
```

To rename a file:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("CurrentName", "DesiredName")
```

To get a file's attributes:

```
attributes = File.GetAttributes(path)
```

Comment: The OP is not after the attributes from the file system, they want the metadata in the file.